# How to save outputs from current directory to another a directory in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read all files in my current directory and would like to save the result on another directory. The code is below but could not get the files in the excepted directory.
Does anyone can help me.

```
for file in *.sorted.bam
do 
samtools index "$file" -o "${file%.sort.bam}".bam | mv /mnt/d/Document/bt2Alignment_result
done
```

Thank you!

Comment: You try to pipe something into `mv`, but `mv` is not designed to process stdin. The pipe does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```sh
for file in *.sorted.bam
do
    outfile="${file%.sorted.bam}.bam"
    samtools index "$filepath" -o "$outfile"
    mv "$outfile" /mnt/d/Document/bt2Alignment_result/
done
```

<sup>**remark:** you were using the glob `*.sorted.bam` while trying to strip the suffix `.sort.bam`</sup>

---

That said, I don't think that you even need to `mv` the output file because `samtools` can directly create it where you want it to be (with the `-o` option). On a different note, sometimes it's convenient to specify a path in the glob, for example `./datadir/*.sorted.bam`, so you should rather do:

```sh
for filepath in ./*.sorted.bam
do
    filename=${filepath##*/}
    outpath=/mnt/d/Document/bt2Alignment_result/"${filename%.sorted.bam}.bam"
    samtools index "$filepath" -o "$outpath"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mv in the next line with *.sorted.bam

```
for file in *.sorted.bam
do 
samtools index "$file" -o "${file%.sorted.bam}".bam 
mv *.sorted.bam /mnt/d/Document/bt2Alignment_result/
done
```

Comment: Not quite; that will relocate all the input files instead of moving the output file

Comment: @Fravadona, on the code `file in *.sorted.bam
do
    outfile="${file%.sorted.bam}.bam"
    samtools index "$filepath" -o "$outfile"
    mv "$outfile" /mnt/d/Document/bt2Alignment_result/
done` .  So how it should be like if I want to save the output file as it is(with no striping the suffix). Additionally, could not get  what this indicates `"$filepath"`. Thank you!

Comment: @adR With my second solution you can use the same filenames for the input and output files, that is, as long as the output file is generated in a different directory than the input file. `filepath` is just a variable name, reminding that the content is `path/to/filename`